# Maximizing the decay rate wrt x of the integral of $\cos(xf(t))$ wrt t over t=[-1,1]

Tags: integration, optimization

I am looking at the following integral

$$
I(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} \cos\left(xf(t)\right) dt
$$

where $-1 \leq f(t) \leq 1$ in the range $-1 \leq t \leq 1$, and where $f(t)$ is odd. I am interested in whether there is a form of $f(t)$ for which the envelope function of $I(x)$ decays fastest as $x \to \infty$.

The best I currently have is
$$
f(t) = \frac{2}{\pi} \sin^{-1}\left(t\right)
$$
producing
$$
I = \frac{\cos(x)}{1-(2x/\pi)^2}
$$
And I honestly have no idea why this form of function works well.

Any help would be very much appreciated!